# android Failure delivering result ResultInfo{...} to activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm creating an activity to manage data of a table (Medicamentos) on a Sqlite database.
I have a listfragment to display the data, and when select from menu (Agregar Medicamentos), redirects to another activity to add a new one. Then return to the fragment and refresh the view (But it crashes on this point).

This is the code of the Fragment:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.geofarma.medser.inventario.db.DbHandler;
import org.geofarma.medser.inventario.entidades.Medicamento;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListMedicamentoFragment extends ListFragment {

    public class MedicamentosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Medicamento> {

        Context m_context;

        public MedicamentosAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId,Medicamento[] medicamentos){
            super(context,textViewResourceId,medicamentos);
            m_context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)m_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_medicamento, parent, false);
            TextView lbl = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreMedicamento);
            lbl.setText(getItem(position).getNombre());
            return row;
        }

    }

    ArrayList<Medicamento> m_medicamento;
    MedicamentosAdapter medicamentosAdapter;
    DbHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity(),null,null,1);

        m_medicamento = dbHandler.readMedicamento();
        Medicamento[] arrayMedicamento = new Medicamento[m_medicamento.size()];
        arrayMedicamento = m_medicamento.toArray(arrayMedicamento);
        dbHandler.close();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        medicamentosAdapter = new MedicamentosAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_medicamento, arrayMedicamento);
        setListAdapter(medicamentosAdapter);
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.add(R.string.action_addMedicamento);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("onOptionsItemSelected", String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));
        if(item.getItemId() == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(),NuevoMedicamento.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1){
            if(data!=null){
                boolean success = data.getBooleanExtra("SUCCESS", false);
                if(success){

                    this.medicamentosAdapter.clear();
                    dbHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity(),null,null,1);
                    m_medicamento = dbHandler.readMedicamento();
                    dbHandler.close();
                    Medicamento[] arrayMedicamento = new Medicamento[this.m_medicamento.size()];
                    arrayMedicamento = m_medicamento.toArray(arrayMedicamento);
                    this.medicamentosAdapter.addAll(arrayMedicamento);
                    this.medicamentosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_medicamentos, container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Medicamento medicamento = m_medicamento.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), medicamento.getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I got the exception when execute the `onActivityResult` method.

**UPDATE:**
This is the log.

```
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {org.geofarma.medser.inventario/org.geofarma.medser.inventario.PrincipalActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2991)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3034)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1188)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:658)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:466)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:258)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at org.geofarma.medser.inventario.ListMedicamentoFragment.onActivityResult(ListMedicamentoFragment.java:92)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:166)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2987)
05-25 23:56:53.080: E/AndroidRuntime(20058):    ... 11 more
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/org.geofarma.medser.inventario/databases/DbMedicamentos' 
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:2072)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1083)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1170)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:844)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at org.geofarma.medser.inventario.db.DbHandler.createMedicamento(DbHandler.java:101)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at org.geofarma.medser.inventario.NuevoMedicamento$1.onClick(NuevoMedicamento.java:31)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
05-25 23:56:53.110: E/SQLiteDatabase(20058):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2230)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2322)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2318)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2283)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:2043)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
05-25 23:56:53.115: E/System(20058):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Post a stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Updated! There is the logcat.

Comment: I think you forget to  `intent.putBooleanExtra("SUCCESS", true);` at your  `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`

Comment: onActivityResult() is not a method of Fragment so you must implement it inside Activity